# Positive definite matricess

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

> Let $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ be positive definite with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ symmetric and positive definite. Show $B$ is also positive definite. Hint: $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is positive definite and clearly determined.

So it is $x^TA^{-\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}}x>0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ and I need to show that this implies $x^TBx>0$. I have no idea how to prove it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For $x\neq 0$, we have:
$$
x'Bx=(A^{1/2}x)'(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})(A^{1/2}x)>0
$$
where we have used the fact that $A^{1/2}x\neq 0$ and the positive definiteness of $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$.